# RecyclerView load images non-linearly

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

My problem is that, I have a RecyclerView and in this I load album arts of music albums, the image is loaded perfectly, but the load is made linearly, so, when drag the RecyclerView slowly, works fine, but when I drag the RecyclerView fast, the load of images takes so much time.
I use an AsyncTask but I do not understand why the threads run linearly, one by one.

This is the create and bind my ViewHolder

```
@Override
public AdaptadorAlbumes.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_album, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v, actividad);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    holder.imgVwPortada.setImageBitmap(Datos.getPortadaDefault());
    holder.imgVwPortada.setTag(position);
    holder.txtNombre.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constantes.ALB_NOMBRE)));
    holder.txtArtista.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constantes.ALB_ARTISTA)));
    ObtenerPortada oP = new ObtenerPortada(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constantes.ALB_ID)), holder.imgVwPortada);
    oP.execute(Datos.getActividadActual());
}
```

This is my ViewHolder

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Activity actividad;
    public TextView txtNombre;
    public TextView txtArtista;
    public ImageView imgVwPortada;
    public RelativeLayout container;

    public ViewHolder(View v, Activity actividad) {
        super(v);
        this.actividad = actividad;
        container = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.artista);
        txtNombre = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
        txtArtista = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtArtista);
        imgVwPortada = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imgVwPortada);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

And this is my AsyncTask class

```
private class ObtenerPortada extends AsyncTask<Activity, Void, Bitmap> {

    long ID;
    private ImageView imv;
    private String path;

    public ObtenerPortada(long ID, ImageView imv) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.imv = imv;
        this.path = imv.getTag().toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Activity... params) {
        WeakReference<Bitmap> bitmap = null;
        try {
            Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Constantes.uriAlbumesArt, ID);
            Bitmap bit = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(params[0].getContentResolver(), trackUri);
            bitmap = new WeakReference<>(ReducirImagenes.reducirBitmap(200, 200, bit));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            bitmap = new WeakReference<>(Datos.getPortadaDefault());
            return null;
        }
        return bitmap.get();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (!imv.getTag().toString().equals(path)) {
            return;
        }
        if(result != null && imv != null){
            imv.setImageBitmap(result);
            imv.setAlpha(0f);
            imv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imv.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(200).setListener(null);
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example that my problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_1yXh6J2Ks

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask by default executes serially on a single background thread. You can override this behavior by using `executeOnExecutor()` instead and supplying your own `Executor` instance (such as a `ThreadPoolExecutor`).

Also, it might help to keep track of the task inside your ViewHolder, so that when it is recycled you can cancel the previous task if that task hasn't started yet.

Comment: +1 for checking the image load is still necessary. You could reuse your existing check in onPostExecute, and do that in doInBackground to avoid loading things that are no longer visible.

Answer (score 0):

Android have limit on how many AsyncTasks can run by default also by default AsyncTasks are run in linear fashion. LinearExucutions is bypassed by executing onExecutor while to avoid limit you have to create your own Thread Pool.

```
 BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue;
 Executor threadPoolExecutor;

workQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(maximumPoolSize);
threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize,    maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS, workQueue);
```

Now execute AsyncTask with executor

```
 new AsyncTaskTest().executeOnExecutor(threadPoolExecutor,null, null, null);
```

Here is an example of [PhotoManager](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/create-threadpool.html), you can also use some advanced image loading libraries that store images outside of JavaHeap - [Fresco Library](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) from Facebook. Fresco also handles to not load images that are not visible.